# After setting the samples parameter, why are gnuplot plots misaligned relative to background TikZ grid?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

In order to run this code, you'll need to have `gnuplot` installed. In addition, you'll have to have your editor/workflow ensure that the `--shell-escape` option is passed to pdflatex, so that TikZ can call `gnuplot`.

Here's a minimum (not) working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[<->] (0,5) node[left] {$x$} -- (0,0) --  (5,0) node[below] {$r$};

        \draw[thick, blue, domain=-5:5, range=0:5, samples = 50, smooth] plot[id=s1] function{-1*sqrt(x) + 1};
        \draw[thick, blue, domain=-5:5, samples = 50, smooth] plot[id=s2] function{sqrt(x) + 1};
        \draw[thick, blue, domain=-5:5] plot[id=s3] function{0};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that the coordinate axes (drawn by `\draw[<->] (0,5) node[left] {$x$} -- (0,0) --  (5,0) node[below] {$r$};`) are drawn on the standard TikZ "background grid".Running the code, you see that the two branches of the square root don't start off at the same location (should start off at (0, 1)), so I say they are misaligned relative to the background TikZ grid (their (0, 1) is not the same as the background grid's (0, 1)).

[image]

However, if I remove the samples parameter, they are correctly aligned relative to the background grid. I don't like the coarser curve because it does not correctly show intersection at (1, 0).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[<->] (0,5) node[left] {$x$} -- (0,0) --  (5,0) node[below] {$r$};

        \draw[thick, blue, domain=-5:5, range=0:5, smooth] plot[id=s1] function{-1*sqrt(x) + 1};
        \draw[thick, blue, domain=-5:5, smooth] plot[id=s2] function{sqrt(x) + 1};
        \draw[thick, blue, domain=-5:5] plot[id=s3] function{0};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I get a smooth curve, along with correct alignment? I am open to using `pgfplots`, if I can figure out how to align the plots produced by `pgfplots` relative to the background TikZ picture (hence, the reason why I have also put in the `pgfplots` tag). This is not something I have had luck with, but `gnuplot` has worked out okay in this regard (except for the current issue).

Comment: Your code does not reproduce the problem you report. Please post an example which can be compiled to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @cfr Do you have gnuplot installed? Do you have --shell-escape as an option when running pdflatex? I put up some pictures showing the output I get from the different pieces of code.

Comment: You can use pgfplots with respect to its own axis. What is it that you want to do with the background?

Comment: @percusse http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226050/how-can-i-align-plots-generated-by-pgfplots-relative-to-a-background-tikz-grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background isn't misaligned compared to the graphs. Rather, the samples don't capture the point $r = 0$. In order to bypass this problem, it's best to manually specify where the samples should be taken, something like this (note how sample points are specified using `\foreach` (i.e. `...`) notation:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[<->] (0,5) node[left] {$x$} -- (0,0) --  (5,0) node[below] {$r$};

        \draw[thick, blue, domain=-5:5, samples at = {-5,4.95,...,1}, smooth] plot[id=s1] function{-1*sqrt(x) + 1};
        \draw[thick, blue, domain=-5:5, samples at = {-5,4.95,...,5}, smooth] plot[id=s2] function{sqrt(x) + 1};
        \draw[thick, blue, domain=-5:5] plot[id=s3] function{0};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, the above code does not work. In the end, I just had to use `pgfplots`, which works well:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% compat=1.11 for implicit pgfplots coordinate matching with TikZ background coords
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[axis lines = none, axis equal]
            \draw[<->] (0,2) node[left] {$x$} -- (0,0) --  (1.5,0) node[below] {$r$};

            \addplot[thick, blue, samples at = {0,0.05,...,1.1}] {sqrt(x) + 1};
            \addplot[thick, blue, samples at = {0,0.05,...,1}] {-1*sqrt(x) + 1};
            \addplot[thick, blue, domain=-1:1.1] {0};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]