# How can I align plots generated by pgfplots relative to a background TikZ grid?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[<->] (0,5) node[left] {$x$} -- (0,0) --  (5,0) node[below] {$r$};

        \begin{axis}[axis lines = none]
            \addplot[samples=50]{sqrt(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It produces the following output:

[image]

I would like to align the start point of sqrt(x) function, with the intersection of the axis lines. How can I do so?

Paul below suggested that I just move Draw inside the axis environment, giving me this output:

[image]

Not quite what I was hoping for, but closer! How is the grid changed by the axis environment?

I needed an answer for this question because I hoped to produce a picture like this, where the blue lines are generated by `pgfplots` -- see the answer to this question for how I produced this image:
[image]

Comment: Move the `\draw` command inside the `axis` environment.

Comment: Well there may be other adjustments required, but with `pgfplots` v1.11 and beyond, the coordinate systems will be shared when `\draw` is used inside `axis`. :-)

Comment: @PaulGessler Thanks so much -- I deleted my "You're kidding me." comment just as you posted your response :p, oh well. Yeah, many other adjustments are required. In particular, I don't understand how the grid is changed by the `axis` environment...(see my post for a picture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the way Paul Gessler presented in his answer. But if for some reason you need to draw the axis lines yourself, or draw anything in relation to the diagram, here is a possibility:

As suggested in a comment, you should move the `\draw` inside the axis environment. But then you have to specify, in relation to which coordinate system you would like to specify the points. There are:

- `axis cs:` the axis coordinate system
- `rel axis cs:` a relative coordinate system, where the complete axis vectors are normalized to 1
- `axis direction cs:` allows to use relative positions and directions
- `axis description cs:` useful for (of course) axis descriptions
- `ticklabel cs:`,`xticklabel cs:`,`yticklabel cs:`,`zticklabel cs:` for positioning the tick labels
- `xticklabel* cs:`,`yticklabel cs:`,`zticklabel cs:` are the same as the non-starred versions, but do not take the size of any tick labels into account

and possibly even more... Usually you will need `axis cs:`, which allows you to easily draw and place nodes inside the axis. You specify coordinates in a coordinate system by e.g.

```
(axis cs:1,2)
```

Note: from pgfplots v1.11 on, `axis cs:` is the standard coordinate system, so you can omit `axis cs:` and simply write e.g. `(1,2)`. But if i interpret your question correctly, this is not the case on your system.

When drawing inside the axis, it is often useful to add `clip=false` to the axis options, so you can draw outside of the specified axis range without it being clipped.

Your MWE would then be

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[axis lines = none,clip=false]
            \addplot[samples=50,domain=0:5]{sqrt(x)};
            \draw[<->] (axis cs:0,3) node[left] {$x$} -- (axis cs:0,0 ) -- (axis cs:5,0) node[below] {$r$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and create

[image: output of MWE]

Comment: If the `pgfplot` compat value is set to 1.11 or higher, you don't need to use `axis cs` explicitly either, since the graph's coordinate system is assumed to be the TikZ picture's coordinate system.

Comment: Also, thank you very much for the `clip = false` tip!

Answer (score 3):

One main point of `pgfplots` is to make it easy to draw axes, so why fall back to TikZ for just that part? The style settings here could be put into one `style` and re-used throughout the document. Then, if you decide to change the style, you only need to update one place in the code.

Another note: the default plotting domain is [-5,5], so half of your 50 samples are thrown away (complex result). I set `domain=0:5` so you get the desired 50 samples spread out over the region you're actually plotting.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
    xlabel=$r$,ylabel=$x$,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=east},
  ]
    \addplot[samples=50,domain=0:5]{sqrt(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]